# How can a Moodle plugin add items to the "Course Administration" list?

Tags: moodle

How can a Moodle plugin add items to the course administration list?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't.

At least you can't if you want to use or implement some functions of your plugin.

This is because the node structure of "Course administration" is built in `/lib/vavigationlib.php` with the protected function `load_course_settings()`. There is no hook in this function calling some other function from your plugin.

The only way to create some other navigation node for your plugin here is to hack this function.

On the other hand, you *can* create navigation nodes for your plugin in the "Navigation" block, by implementing the `your_plugin_extends_navigation()` function in your plugin `lib.php`.